# TCPDUMP: Bitmasking

Tags: networking, ip, tcpdump, packet-sniffers

I am taking a digital securities class and I dont understand one of the examples on bitmasking.

To find IPv4 packets they say run this command

tcpdump IP[0] & 0xf0 = 4

I believe that this is wrong, the bit mask correctly only selects the first 4 bits of the IP header (which is the version number) and sets all the bits for the internet header length to 0.

But shouldnt the answer be

tcpdump IP[0] & 0xf0 = 0x40

This states to set all bits in the first byte of the IP packet header except for the first 4 bits (which is the version number) to 0 and to only show packets with this value equal to 0100 0000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This states to set all bits in the first byte of the IP packet header except for the first 4 bits (which is the version number) to 0

More correctly, it *selects* the first 4 bits of the first byte of the IP packet header, and returns a value in which the lower 4 bits are zero.

So you *are* correct, in that `tcpdump IP[0] & 0xf0 = 4` will ***NEVER*** succeed (as `IP[0] & 0xf0` is in the range `0x00` through `0xf0`, with the low-order nibble being 0, so it can ***NEVER*** equal 4), and `IP[0] & 0xf0 = 0x40` will succeed only if the IP version number in the IP header is 4 (rather than, for example, 6).